# Google IP for PageSpeed Insights and issues with DNS = wrong results

Tags: pagespeed-insights, google-pagespeed-insights-api

I am having a website hosted by several servers multiple continents. I use AWS Route 53 and geolocation. When i test the website with the PageSpeed Insights i get a really bad TTFB and that is strange. I investigated further and found out that the Google server (66.249.81.195) is actually located in Netherlands / Europe but was fetching data from our web server in the USA. After some investigation using the iplocation.net i found out that from 7-8 providers of ip records, only one correctly located the IP in the Netherlands, and the rest refers to the USA. So, my question is, how am I suppose to direct google to the correct server, if most records say it is an American IP, when in fact is located in Europe?

I am expecting that the IP records from Google PageSpeed Insights are correctly located.

Comment: Google is using US registered IP addresses in European locations. This messes up the Geolocation, and creates a very unreliable way to assess TTFB. I hope Google that is determined in providing technology for speed, repair this situation as soon as possible.